# PHP use $xml->xpath multiple

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I want use `$xml->xpath` for an `XML` file.

The first line below works successfully but second line does not work.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(decode(file_get_contents('http://www.file.net/name.xml')));
if($xml) {
    $dataObjects = $xml->xpath('/feed/in/test[@id="0603162"]'); // First line
    $xmlObjects = $dataObjects->xpath('/get/type[@name="333"]'); // Second line
    print_r($xmlObjects);
}
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($dataObjects);` return ?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#25 (4) { ["@attributes"]=> array(7) { ["a_id"]=> string(7) "4142502" ["ad_2"]=> string(7) "4503374" ["date"]=> string(10) "06.03.2016" ["id"]=> string(7) "4260040" ["std"]=> string(20) "060316234" ["status"] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made too many errors as in Xpath syntax so in logic. A code may be about such: 1) play the second xpath to each elements but not for a list 2) use dot at begginig of the second xpath to find into an element but not in the  full  document

```
if($xml) {
    $dataObjects = $xml->xpath('/feed/in/test[@id="0603162]'); // First line
    foreach($dataObjects as $xmlObject) {
        $Objs = $xmlObject->xpath('./get/type[@name="333]'); // Second line
        foreach($Objs as $Obj) 
          print_r($Obj);
        }  
}
```